# Multi criteria sorting of a list of objects with Guava Ordering

Tags: java, sorting, gwt, guava

I have a class WHICH CANNOT implement comparable, but needs to be sorted based on 2 fields. How can I achieve this with Guava?

Let's say the class is:

```
class X {
  String stringValue;
  java.util.Date dateValue;
}
```

And I have a list of these:

```
List<X> lotsOfX;
```

I want to sort them based on the value field first and then based on dateValue descending within each 'group' of 'value' fields.

What I have been doing so far is:

```
List<X> sortedList = ImmutableList.copyOf(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(dateValueSortFunction).reverse().sortedCopy(lotsOfX));
sortedList = ImmutableList.copyOf(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(stringValueSortFunction).sortedCopy(sortedList));
```

The functions are defined as:

```
public class DateValueSortFunction<X> implements Function<X, Long> {

    @Override
      public Long apply(X input) {
        return input.getDateValue().getTime();  //returns millis time
      }
}
```

And:

```
public class StringValueSortFunction<X> implements Function<X, Integer> {

      @Override
        public Integer apply(X input) {
          if(input.getStringValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Something"))
            return 0;
          else if(input.getStringValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Something else"))
            return 1;
          else
            return 2;
        }
}
```

Expected output in `sortedList` is:

```
Something   03/18/2013
Something   03/17/2013
Something else  03/20/2013
Something else  03/19/2013
....
```

My approach works but is obviously inefficient for traversing the list twice. Is there a better way of doing this?

I am using this in a GWT app. Implementing comparable is not an option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suspect you want [`Ordering.compound`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound-java.util.Comparator-). You *could* do it all in one statement, but I'd use:

```
Ordering<X> primary = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(stringValueSortFunction);
Ordering<X> secondary = Ordering.natural()
                              .onResultOf(dateValueSortFunction)
                              .reverse();
Ordering<X> compound = primary.compound(secondary);

List<X> sortedList = compound.immutableSortedCopy(lotsOfX);
```

Comment: Holy cow ! Thanks for this, saved me a lot of IF...ELSE cases ! I was in for a nightmare of cross conditions.

Answer (score 17):

A less functional, but arguably cleaner, solution:

```
new Ordering<X>() {
  public int compare(X x1, X x2) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(x1.stringValue, x2.stringValue)
      .compare(x2.dateValue, x1.dateValue) // flipped for reverse order
      .result();
  }
}.immutableSortedCopy(listOfXs);
```

Comment: I did look into this but I read that .compare would expect the inputs to implement comparable. So if I understand correctly, in this case it would sort the strings alphabetically? But I needed to put in my own custom sort function.

Comment: If you want to sort the `String`s using a custom comparator, then you can just use `compare(x1.stringValue, x2.stringValue, new MyCustomStringComparator())`.

Comment: I see. Well as, long as one doesn't perform better than the other I am fine with both. I think the other answer is acceptably clean.

Comment: For everyone who thinks swapping the arguments to get reverse order is too subtle, you can pass in a comparator as the third argument and use `Collections.reverseOrder()` which than reads: `.compare(x1.dateValue, x2.dateValue, reverseOrder())` (assuming you're using static imports.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 provides methods on Comparator to concisely specify chained comparators.  Together with the newly-introduced List.sort, you can do:

```
lotsOfX.sort(
    Comparator.comparingInt(x -> stringValueSortFunction.apply(x.stringValue))
        .thenComparing(x -> x.dateValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

This mutates the list, of course -- make a copy first if you want to leave the original list unchanged, or wrap the comparator in an Ordering and use `immutableSortedCopy` if you want an immutable copy.